# functions not successfully executing during submit action

Tags: javascript

I have the following code present in a Javascript file. When a click occurs on this form, I want the `postAction` function to be executed. Right now though I see the lines of code within `postAction` gets processed (via web developer), for some reason the `postAction` function does seem to be successfully executed. I'm suspecting it has to do something with `preventDefault` or `return false`. See any issues with the code below?

```
ssoWelcome: (function () {
    var $p = $('<form class="full controls"><p>Welcome <span class="username"></span>!</p><input type="submit" value="Continue" name="welcome" class="welcomeBtn"></form>');
    $p.submit(function (e) {
        C.options.postAction('redirect');
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    });
    return $p;
}())
```

Comment: so you want to submit a dynamic form?

Comment: There is nothing on this form other than a button. On the button click, I want to execute some functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right in that it's something to do with `preventDefault`. The line

```
preventDefault(e);
```

should be

```
e.preventDefault();
```

However, assuming this is jQuery, the `return false` does the same thing as `e.preventDefault()` so you don't need to call it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all shouldn't you be doing:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply obtain appending form in the document and performing live function like this :

```
var $p = $('<form class="full controls"><p>Welcome <span class="username"></span>!</p><input type="submit" value="Continue" name="welcome" class="welcomeBtn"></form>');
$(document).append($p);

$('.welcomeBtn').live('click', (function (e) {
    //do your function here
    return false;
});
```